# Calculation of Active Share Measure

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I observe the weights for each stock in a set of portfolios. I would like to compute the "active share" measure. This is defined as `active_share_{ij} = active_share_{ji} = \sum^N_k | \omega^k_i - \omega^k_j |` where `N` is the number of all stocks that exist in the market, `\omega^k_i` is the weight of stock `k` in portfolio `i` and the vertical bars indicate the absolute difference. Note that the sum runs over all stocks in the market: if, for example, portfolio `i` holds stock `k` while portfolio `j` does not, then weight `\omega^k_j=0` and the absolute difference should evaluate to `| \omega^k_i - 0 |`.

In my data structure, I observe the three relevant pieces of information `portfolio`, `stock` and `weight`. In my MWE, this looks like

```
  portfolio   stock  weight
0        P1  stock1     0.3
1        P1  stock2     0.6
2        P1  stock3     0.1
3        P2  stock2     0.1
4        P2  stock3     0.2
5        P2  stock4     0.3
6        P2  stock5     0.1
7        P2  stock8     0.3
8        P3  stock3     0.4
9        P3  stock4     0.6
```

I would like to produce

```
                         active_share
portfolio_i portfolio_j              
P1          P1                    0.0
            P2                    1.6
            P3                    1.8
P2          P1                    1.6
            P2                    0.0
            P3                    1.0
P3          P1                    1.8
            P2                    1.0
            P3                    0.0
```

Lets look at the calculation of pair `(P1,P2)` as an example: `|0.3-0|+|0.6-0.1|+|0.1-0.2|+|0-0.3|+|0-0.1|+|0-0.3| = 1.6`

My few lines of code are capable of producing the results. However, I am facing a very large dataset and need to increase the performance.

**Do you see a way to optimize the computation?** For example by making use of the fact that the relation is symmetric, i.e. the measure for (i,j) is the same as for (j,i)?

MWE:

```
# generate example data
data  = {
    'portfolio': ['P1','P1','P1','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P3','P3'], 
    'stock': ['stock1','stock2','stock3','stock2','stock3','stock4','stock5','stock8','stock3','stock4'], 
    'weight':[0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# help dataframe
df['key'] = df.groupby('portfolio').ngroup()
portfolio_list = df['portfolio'].unique()
groups = df['key'].unique()
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([portfolio_list, groups], names=['portfolio','key'])
join = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=[]).reset_index()

# perform some sort of outer join
composite = df.merge(join, on='key', suffixes=('_i','_j'), how='inner')
composite = composite.loc[:,composite.columns!='key']
composite.rename(columns={'weight':'weight_i'}, inplace=True)

# identify whether counterparty has same holdings
composite = composite.merge(df, left_on=['portfolio_j','stock'], right_on=['portfolio','stock'], how='left', suffixes=('_i','_j'))
composite = composite.loc[:,~composite.columns.isin(['portfolio','key'])]
composite.rename(columns={'weight':'weight_j'}, inplace=True)

# compute the sum of absolute differences for overlapping portfolio
composite['abs_weight_difference'] = (composite['weight_i'] - composite['weight_j']).abs()
result = composite.groupby(['portfolio_i','portfolio_j'])['abs_weight_difference'].sum().to_frame('sum_overlap')

# compute the sum of weights of stocks that are in portfolio i but not in j
result['sum_unique_i'] = composite.loc[composite['weight_j'].isnull()].groupby(['portfolio_i','portfolio_j'])['weight_i'].sum()

# add sum of weights of stocks (1) in portfolio overlap, (2) distinct to portfolio i, (3) distinct to portolio j
result = result.reset_index()
result = result.merge(result, left_on=['portfolio_i','portfolio_j'], right_on=['portfolio_j','portfolio_i'])
result = result.loc[:,['portfolio_i_x','portfolio_j_x','sum_overlap_x','sum_unique_i_x','sum_unique_i_y']]
result.columns = ['sum_unique_j' if col=='sum_unique_i_y' else col[:-2] for col in result.columns]

result = result.fillna(0)
result.set_index(['portfolio_i','portfolio_j'], inplace=True)
result = result.sum(axis=1).to_frame(name='active_share')
```

Edit: Currently, it takes 5.82 minutes on a small subset of my dataset (as a future reference point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a much fast solution easier:

```
# generate example data
data  = {
    'portfolio': ['P1','P1','P1','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P3','P3'], 
    'stock': ['stock1','stock2','stock3','stock2','stock3','stock4','stock5','stock6','stock3','stock4'], 
    'weight':[0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6]}
holdings = pd.DataFrame(data)

# compute absolute difference for stocks in both portfolios
stock_join = holdigs.merge(holdings, on=['stock'], suffixes=('_i','_j'), how='inner')
stock_join['difference'] = (stock_join['weight_i'] - stock_join['weight_j']).abs()

# compute the absolute difference for stocks that are distinct to portfolio i and j
result = stock_join.groupby(['portfolio_i','portfolio_j'])['weight_i','weight_j','difference'].sum()
result.columns = [f'ovlp_sum_{col}' for col in result.columns]

result['sum_distinct_i'] = 1.0-result['ovlp_sum_weight_i']
result['sum_distinct_j'] = 1.0-result['ovlp_sum_weight_j']

# add the parts together
result['active_share'] = result['sum_distinct_i'] + result['ovlp_sum_difference'] + result['sum_distinct_j']

result = result.loc[:,'active_share']
```

This evaluates to

```
portfolio_i  portfolio_j
P1           P1             0.0
             P2             1.6
             P3             1.8
P2           P1             1.6
             P2             0.0
             P3             1.0
P3           P1             1.8
             P2             1.0
             P3             0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to `pivot` the data first, then use `broadcast` to compute your actual data:

```
a = df.pivot_table(index='portfolio', 
               columns='stock', 
               values='weight',
               fill_value=0)

idx = a.index
a = a.to_numpy()

pd.DataFrame(np.abs(a[:,None] - a[None,:]).sum(axis=-1),
             index=idx, columns=idx)
```

Output:

```
portfolio   P1   P2   P3
portfolio               
P1         0.0  1.6  1.8
P2         1.6  0.0  1.0
P3         1.8  1.0  0.0
```

From there, you can `stack` to get the expected output in the question:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.abs(a[:,None] - a[None,:]).sum(axis=-1),
             index=idx, columns=idx).stack()
```

gives:

```
portfolio  portfolio
P1         P1           0.0
           P2           1.6
           P3           1.8
P2         P1           1.6
           P2           0.0
           P3           1.0
P3         P1           1.8
           P2           1.0
           P3           0.0
dtype: float64
```

---

**Update**: since you have two many Stocks/Portfolios, you can choose to loop over `Stocks`, which will reduce memory requirement:

```
a = df.pivot_table(index='portfolio', 
           columns='stock', 
           values='weight',
           fill_value=0)

idx = a.index

ret = pd.DataFrame(0, index=idx, columns=idx)

for col in a:
    u = a[col].to_numpy()
    ret += np.abs(u-u[:,None])
```

Outcome:

```
portfolio   P1   P2   P3
portfolio               
P1         0.0  1.6  1.8
P2         1.6  0.0  1.0
P3         1.8  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: That looks extremely easy and readable, thanks. Thinking in SQL terms is not always good. However, I receive a `Killed: 9` response, likely due to memory issues. This is a problem because I tested this only on a smaller subset of my data. I am talking about 20,000 portfolios and 30,000 stocks. My initial proposal seems to be more memory efficient as I didn't run in any issues previously.

Comment: Yes, broadcast does generate a data of size `num_portfolios x num_portfolios x num_stocks` before taking sums.

Comment: No, the formula is correct. I look at all possible pairs of portfolios `i` and `j`, correct, but compare the weights of portfolios `i`and `j` only for the same stock `k`. Your suggested formula suggests that I compare weights of different stocks, which should not be the case.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Sorry for the lack of precision: I should have pointed out that if stock `k` is not in portfolio `i`, the weight is `0`. Please see my example calculation in the edited opening post.

Comment: To estimate the required memory, can I do the following naive calculation? Currently, I have a 978 (stocks) x 7825 (portfolios) numpy array which evaluates to 61222800 bytes or 61 MB in memory. Then, the array 7825 x 7825 x 978 has size 61MB * 7825 = 477 GB? That would obviously not be doable...

Comment: That sounds about right. See update for a looping solution.

Comment: Thanks, I already (successfully) tried that: From 5.82 min I am down to something like 1.2 min (incl. pivoting). Plus it looks much cleaner. I will go with this. I appreciate your effort, thanks so much.